# Python Sort Frequency

Tags: python

I just started using python in school and i have a question i have been trying to figure out for a while

The problem is sort a list by frequency and the list also contains strings 
for ex given function call

```
SortByFrequency(['pie', 6, 'pie', 9, 6, 7, 9, 9]
```

it should return

```
[9, 9, 9, 'pie', 'pie', 6, 6, 7]
```

How could i find the solution using python thanks
My code i already tried was trying to using a dictionary and print the elements somehow

```
my_Dict ={}
for i in mylist:
       if i not in my_dict:
and count the occurrences
```

Comment: your code makes no sense....the `if` will never happen, random `and`, spacing problems

Comment: You had a good start but didn't get very far. Forget sorting for a moment, just try and build a dictionary with the counts, e.g. `{'pie': 2, 6: 2, 9: 3, 7: 1}`. Write some actual code.

Answer (score 1):

If this is not some sort of school assignment that not allow to use python module, don't reinvent the wheel, it can be done as below using collections module

```
import collections
def SortByFrequency(lst):
  return list(collections.Counter(lst).elements())

SortByFrequency(['pie', 6, 'pie', 9, 6, 7, 9, 9])
# this return [9, 9, 9, 'pie', 'pie', 6, 6, 7]
```

My own attempt to solve this with dictionary would be

```
def SortByFrequency(mylist):
    my_dict = {}
    for i in mylist:
        my_dict[i] = my_dict.get(i,0) + 1
    return sorted(sorted(mylist,key=str), key=my_dict.get, reverse=True)

SortByFrequency(['pie', 6, 'pie', 9, 6, 7, 9, 9])
# but this does not guarantee the order when we have multiple values with same frequency
# this will return [9, 9, 9, 6, 6, 'pie', 'pie', 7]
```

Comment: Yes, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You were on the way to build the dictionary. Complete it like this:

```
    if i not in my_dict:
        my_dict[i] = 0 # define this entry
    my_dict[i] += 1 # increment it (number of occurrences of i)
```

Then you just need to sort it, using the dictionary as key:

```
def sortByFrequency(mylist):
    my_dict ={}
    for i in mylist:
        if i not in my_dict:
            my_dict[i] = 0
        my_dict[i] += 1
    return sorted(mylist, key=lambda i: -my_dict[i])
```

The minus sign is a quick way to sort in descending order. Note that it is more common to write the function with an initial lower case letter, as an initial capital is commonly reserved for class names.

Comment: is their any way to do it without the lambda i dont even know what it is? and could explain what the last snippet of code is doing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create auxiliary dict with counters

```
list_ = ['pie', 6, 'pie', 9, 6, 7, 9, 9]
dict_ = {}
for i in list_:
  dict_[i] = dict_.get(i, 0) - 1
# Your dict_ now is following:
# {6: -2, 7: -1, 9: -3, 'pie': -2}
sorted(list_, key=dict_.get)
#=> [9, 9, 9, 'pie', 6, 'pie', 6, 7]
```